# Running a bitcoind docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile, bitcoind

Thanks to the bitcoin.stack community I have successfully launched a bitcoind docker with an external volume which has the block data

Currently its in 100% sync but I am facing an issue to get information using bitcoin-cli I need to run bitcoind -reindex and then add txindex=1 into bitcoin.conf

As I pulled the docker image from docker hub I do not have any control over its docker file and I have 140GB+ blockchain data that I do not wanna discard and start over

How do I run --reindex on an docker container ?

Answer (score -1):

While your container is running you can run `docker exec -it <mybitcoindcontainer> /bin/sh`. This should give you a shell inside your running container. You can then run your choice of commands at the shell prompt.